# Worksheet IF statements with AirTable

Tags: excel, vba, airtable

Im using Airtable (Online Excel Equivalent with their own similar [Formulas](https://support.airtable.com/hc/en-us/articles/203255215-Formula-Field-Reference))but I can't seem to get this to work properly.

So I have three values (UE, PE, EE) which are being used for the following columns (GradeF, ZipcodeF, SchoolF) The formula will be applied to the column "Eligible". So overall what I'm trying to do is If Grade is "UE", then mark as "UE". If Grade is "PE" then determine If Zipcode is "EE" or "PE", or School is "EE", or "PE" if so then mark as "PE" otherwise "UE". If Grade is "EE" then determine If Zipcode is "EE", or School is "EE" if so then mark as "EE" otherwise "UE".

```
IF(GradeF = "UE", "UE", IF(GradeF = "PE", IF(OR(ZipcodeF = "EE", ZipcodeF = "PE", SchoolF = "EE", SchoolF = "PE"), "PE","UE", IF(GradeF = "EE", IF(OR(ZipcodeF = "EE", SchoolF = "EE"), "EE", "UE" ,"")))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier if you work backward from your most common case ("UE").  I've never used Airtable, but this should be the logic (line breaks for clarity):

```
IF(AND(GradeF="EE",OR(ZipcodeF="EE",SchoolF="EE")),"EE",
IF(AND(GradeF="PE",OR(ZipcodeF="EE",SchoolF="EE",
ZipcodeF="PE",SchoolF="PE")),"PE","UE"))
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! Just realized I needed If GradeF="EE" then if ZipcodeF or SchoolF = "PE" but figured it out by copying the first line and replacing "EE" with "PE" and adding another parentheses at the end.